# How to correctly move a sprite image in SDL Perl

Tags: perl, sdl

So i have created a sprite animation using SDL Perl, the good news is the sprite image is moving and the bad news is that the moving sprite is not exactly aligned in an 47x47 `SDLx::Rect`

I can't really explain what's going on so here's the screenshot

[image]

And here's the Sprite image i used

[image]

And finally my code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use SDLx::Sprite::Animated;
use SDL;
use SDLx::App;
use SDL::Rect;

my $anim = SDLx::Sprite::Animated->new(
    image => "ex.png",
    step_x => 47,
    step_y => 1,
    rect => SDL::Rect->new(0,0,47,47),
    ticks_per_frame => 6,
    type => "circular",
);
$anim->step_y(0);
$anim->start();

my $app = SDLx::App->new( dt=>0.02, exit_on_quit => 1, w=> 200, h => 200 );
$app->add_show_handler(
    sub{
        my ($step,$app) = @_;
        $app->draw_rect([0,0,$app->w,$app->h],0);
        $anim->draw($app->surface);
        $app->update();
        $app->delay(2);
    }
);

$app->run();
```

Need your help, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your sprite sheet is 313 pixels wide and have 6 images. Killing last column, `312/6=52`, far from 47 that you claimed. Also your step_y is 1 when it should be 0.

Comment: If you'll put 0 in the `step_y=>1` you'll get an error `Illegal division by zero` so that's why i set `$anim->step_y(0);` so i'll try 52x52 and thanks for replying though, appreciate it :)